# How to use a UISplitTableViewController correctly to display two UITableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am (still) in the process of converting an iPhone app to a universal app.

I want to push a UISplitViewController onto a UIView. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9609625/459116) I am trying to create this flow:

UIView -> UISplitViewController (containing two UITableViews that I use in the iPhone version) -> UIView

I want the button attached to this IBAction to make the tableview appear on iPhone (which is all set up and working) and the SplitViewController appear on the iPad:

```
-(IBAction)makeStory:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"makeStory:");


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {      
   //Code here to push split view.


} else {
    //I am an iPhone! 
    makeStoryTableViewController = [[MakeStoryTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MakeStoryTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:makeStoryTableViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];


}       
}
```

I've read tutorials [here](http://jonathanhui.com/ios-universal-application) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad) - but I can't get my head around how to add it to an existing app correctly. I would appreciate some help / direction so I can implement a UISplitViewController correctly in this universal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "push" a split view controller or add it on top of another view.  It has to be the root view controller of the window.

In your IBACtion you could do something as simple as:

appWindow.rootViewController = aSplitViewController;

Of course, you have to get a reference to your app's window, and you have to get aSplitViewController which is initialized with left and right view controllers from somewhere...